# How can two brothers contact?

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

At C language:

I have a father that make two sons at a loop by `fork()`, I want that each son will have (at pid_t type) the process ID of his brother.

I try do this via pipe but I didn't success.
Do you have any idea how can I do this?

I did this via `(write(pos[1],getpid(),sizeof(pid_t))` (this son send to his brother his pid)
but it doesn't work...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write needs a pointer to the data to write. `getpid` returns a process id, not a pointer to a process id. You need to store the return value from `getpid` in variable:

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
write(pos[1], &pid, sizeof(pid_t);
```

I am assuming that pos[1] holds the file descriptor of the pipe to the sibling.

Comment: Now it's working I tried something similar before but I didn't success.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The sibling processes can't communicate via a pipe with each other, typically. But you can make tha parent send the pid of the other sibling, to each sibling. To do this you will of course need to set up two pipes, one to each child.

```
  parent
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
son1   son2
```

The parent will need to create one son at a time, then when it knows both have succeeded in starting, it can send the pid of each child processes' sibling, to each.

Comment: And I can do this via named_pipe?

Comment: @unwind Why can't they?

Comment: @Zhongzhi: [they can](https://gist.github.com/zed/1f96e0237a66cb541fdc#file-send-pid-to-brother-c-L58).